# PHP: How to remove/disable a selection from a checkbox group if the value is already selected and stored in database previously

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, checkbox

Right now I am coding in PHP & HTML

---

I need to make a selection from the checkbox group
and it goes like this:

1. The value in the dropdown menu is retrieved from the value stored in the database in table `subject`. So the checkbox options will appears as (for example) Mathematics, Algebra, Calculus, English, Linguistic etc. -- *I have no problem with displaying this one.*

   **Table subject**

   ```
   subject_id       subject_name
   ==========       ============
        1            Mathematics
        2            Algebra
        3            Calculus
        4            English
        5            Linguistic
   ```
2. So after that, a student can choose their `subject` and it will be stored in another table named `student_subject` where it stores the `student_id` and the `subject_id` (*to store what subjects did a student chose*)
   Example:

**table student_subject**

```
    student_id       subject_id
    ==========       ===========
        1                 1
        1                 2                                           
        1                 3
        2                 1  
        2                 3
```

3. Now, the student comes again to add another subject to his profile. The same checkbox option will be displayed as mentioned earlier in (1) but I would love to disabled/remove/not display the already selected option from being selectable again to avoid redundancy.

I really have no idea on how to create this function. I know there are a lot of experienced programmers and developera here so I wish you could show me the right way. Your guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove/disabled/not display the existing subjects.

First, you should check for existing rows for `student_subject` table and render it in HTML checkbox as selected.

Second, while student makes changes for subject selection in edit mode, check with the database rows with student and subject ids in a loop.

If submitted subject id for the student is not available in the database, insert that value to the table.

If submitted subject id for the student is available in the database, do nothing with it.

Check for the removed subject from submitted values with the database, and delete from the database.

If you want to disable existing subjects, use `readonly` to the checkbox if the subject is assigned to the student.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea:

On your #2 where a table will store student_id and subject_id, I think it's best that whenever you store value to subject_id- you just serialize the value by storing it on an php array in that way you can iterate the whole array if the field was checked or not.

Json_encode is also good since it will be a string and same as serialize

Example:

```
Student_id       Subject_ID
999-0518         a:{this is the serialize value };
```

Then when you query the result it will be serialize, then use unserialize function and do a loop to iterate the results, same goes when you json_encode; just perform json_decode() function and perform loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query which only picks up subjects which ID isn't in `student_subject`.

It would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `subject` 
WHERE `subject_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `subject_id` FROM `student_subject` WHERE `student_id` = '1'
)
```

*(you can ommit the inner `where` clause if you don't want this to be user specific)*

and then build the `<select>` element based on the array returned from it.